# Are free shell accounts safe?

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to identify how safe the free shell accounts provided by the likes of [shellmix.com](http://www.shellmix.com) are. I have never used one myself but want to suggest it to someone interested in learning shell programming. Are they safe to use for this purpose? What should I watch out for?

Comment: Consider the advantages of a [Live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) distribution too. No privacy issues, no security restrictions, no network speed annoyances.

Comment: ive used shellmix. its ok. a livecd is better imho, or even better install virtualbox (if you have a multi-core cpu)

Comment: VirtualBox and a Linux distro of your choice are free. Unlike mucking around with cygwin or mingw, you have a complete native OS to work with and the security worries from rogue admins go away.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A general rule of thumb I go by is only trust a machine as much as you trust its root user(s), both in terms of technical competence (especially in security), and general trustworthiness.  Since it is unlikely you know the admins of [shellmix](http://www.shellmix.com) very well, it's probably a bad idea to trust the machine(s) your account is on any more than you would any random box on the Internet.  If all you do is write shell scripts and compile the occasional hello world, you should be fine.  Assume everything you type into the remote shell can potentially be read by others.  Do not put anything you wouldn't want public there, even temporarily.  This includes hard-coding personal information or information about your own computer like host names, user names, directory layout, etc. in shell scripts.  As mentioned by @SamBisbee in the comments, use a unique password you never reuse for anything else.  Also, there are security risks to forwarding X11 connections (i.e. `ssh -X` to the shellmix machine) from an untrusted machine so I'd avoid doing that as well.

Comment: I agree with you general paranoia, but are there any documented cases of folks setting up a full-featured shell environment as a honeypot?  I mean, I've had nyx.net and sdf.lonestar.org accounts over the years, and I've never heard of such weirdness as you propose could happen.

Comment: I also have never heard of such honeypots but there is always the possibility of a user who manages privilege escalation or even a rogue admin.  Nevertheless, "it's never happened before" is not exactly the most sound security principle to lean on.

Comment: Also, use a throw away password. As root they can see your unshadowed password and rip that sucker. And under NO circumstances should you EVER have private keys (GPG, SSH, etc.) on that box.

Comment: Note that even semi-modern ssh has both -X and -Y. In those versions, -X is much safer. See the ssh docs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? Most likely you can do whatever you're trying to do within the comfort of your Windows OS (and your own machine).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a bash-like shell for Windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), which might be an alternative or extension to a shell account. A benefit is, that you can watch in a GUI-filemanager what effect your mkdir, touch, rmdir ... - commands had from a second perspective.

Another benefit is the rich toolset (grep, sed, awk, ...) of the GNU-toolkit, if you work on Windows. After being used to it, you will be happy not to miss them.

Comment: Why only a handful of utils? Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and be done with it.

Comment: Because it is lean, and convenient, if you rarely use windows. For real work, I use Linux with virtual Desktops and so on - I never liked cygwin.